# Firestore query data based on string name

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to query data in FB/FS.

Lets say I have data like this:

```
"items": {
    "id1":{
        "phrase": "the cat got hit by a van"
    }
    "id2":{
        "phrase": "the frog got hit by a bad driver"
    }
    "id3":{
        "phrase": "the dog got hit by a car"
    }
    "id4":{
        "phrase": "the deer got hit by a bus"
    }
}
```

If I wanted to query data where `phrase` contains "**cat**" or "**dog** || **van**", how would I do this? Or can it be done?

I tried

```
db.collection("items").where("phrase", "array-contains", urlParams.get('s')).get().then((querySnapshot) => { ... }
```

but `phrase` is not an array, its a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in Firebase - see this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search)

Your options are really to either change your data structure to make use of Firebase features, query the entire collection by retrieving all documents and searching through them client side (which can very quickly become very expensive), or to switch to a different database solution - potentially something SQL based is what you are looking for.

Comment: was afraid of this. thanks for the quick response.